# Acumatica Pagination Implementation for Processing Screen does not returns all applicable values

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have tried to implement pagination for my custom processing screen but not getting all the required values in the grid.

1. If I am using below code, where I did not implemented pagination and directly using BQL in the foreach() loop for getting the records, I am getting all the applicable values.

```
public PXCancel<KNPIPaymentFilter> cancel;
        public PXFilter<KNPIPaymentFilter> KNPIFilter;
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXFilteredProcessing<SOOrder, KNPIPaymentFilter> KNPIProcessOrders;

        protected bool _PayMethodChanged = false;
        protected bool _PayActionChanged = false;

        public virtual void KNPIPaymentFilter_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            _PayMethodChanged = !sender.ObjectsEqual<KNPIPaymentFilter.paymentMethodID>(e.Row, e.OldRow);
            _PayActionChanged = !sender.ObjectsEqual<KNPIPaymentFilter.payPalInvAction>(e.Row, e.OldRow);
        }

        public IEnumerable kNPIProcessOrders()
        {
            if (_PayMethodChanged || _PayActionChanged)
                KNPIProcessOrders.Cache.Clear();

            KNPIPaymentFilter filter = PXCache<KNPIPaymentFilter>.CreateCopy(KNPIFilter.Current);
            if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.SL)
                yield break;

            foreach (SOOrder order in PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderTypeConstants.salesOrder>, And<SOOrder.paymentMethodID, Equal<Required<KNPIPaymentFilter.paymentMethodID>>,
                                And<SOOrder.status, NotEqual<SOOrderStatus.completed>>>>>.Select(this, this.KNPIFilter.Current.PaymentMethodID))
            {
                KNPIPayments PayPalPayment = new PXSelect<KNPIPayments, Where<KNPIPayments.acmOrderNbr, Equal<Required<KNPIPayments.acmOrderNbr>>,
                                                 And<KNPIPayments.acmOrderType, Equal<Required<KNPIPayments.acmOrderType>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<KNPIPayments.lineNbr>>>
                                                (this).SelectWindowed(0, 1, order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType);
                if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.RE)
                {
                    if (PayPalPayment == null || (PayPalPayment != null && PayPalPayment.PayPalInvoiceStatus == KNPIConstants.CANCELLED))
                        yield return order;
                }
                else if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.CH)
                {
                    if (PayPalPayment != null && PayPalPayment.PayPalInvoiceStatus == KNPIConstants.SENT)
                        yield return order;
                }
            }
            KNPIProcessOrders.Cache.IsDirty = false;
        }
```

2. But when I am implementing pagination logic like below, I am not getting any of the record in the grid. I have debugged the code and found out in the list object it is loading only 19 records initially but after that other records are not at all loading in the object.

```
        public PXCancel<KNPIPaymentFilter> cancel;
        public PXFilter<KNPIPaymentFilter> KNPIFilter;
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXFilteredProcessing<SOOrder, KNPIPaymentFilter> KNPIProcessOrders;       

        protected bool _PayMethodChanged = false;
        protected bool _PayActionChanged = false;

        public virtual void KNPIPaymentFilter_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            _PayMethodChanged = !sender.ObjectsEqual<KNPIPaymentFilter.paymentMethodID>(e.Row, e.OldRow);
            _PayActionChanged = !sender.ObjectsEqual<KNPIPaymentFilter.payPalInvAction>(e.Row, e.OldRow);
        }

        public IEnumerable kNPIProcessOrders()
        {
            if (_PayMethodChanged || _PayActionChanged)
                KNPIProcessOrders.Cache.Clear();

            KNPIPaymentFilter filter = PXCache<KNPIPaymentFilter>.CreateCopy(KNPIFilter.Current);
            if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.SL)
                yield break;            

            PXSelectBase<SOOrder> cmd = new PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderTypeConstants.salesOrder>, And<SOOrder.status, NotEqual<SOOrderStatus.completed>,
                                                           And<SOOrder.paymentMethodID, Equal<Optional<KNPIPaymentFilter.paymentMethodID>>>>>>(this);

            int startRow = PXView.StartRow;
            int totalRows = 0;
            List<object> list = cmd.View.Select(new[] { KNPIFilter.Current }, null, PXView.Searches,
                                        PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows);

            foreach (SOOrder order in list)
            {
                KNPIPayments PayPalPayment = new PXSelect<KNPIPayments, Where<KNPIPayments.acmOrderNbr, Equal<Required<KNPIPayments.acmOrderNbr>>,
                                                 And<KNPIPayments.acmOrderType, Equal<Required<KNPIPayments.acmOrderType>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<KNPIPayments.lineNbr>>>
                                                (this).SelectWindowed(0, 1, order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType);
                if (this.KNPIFilter.Current.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.RE)
                {
                    if (PayPalPayment == null || (PayPalPayment != null && PayPalPayment.PayPalInvoiceStatus == KNPIConstants.CANCELLED))
                        yield return order;
                }
                else if (this.KNPIFilter.Current.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.CH)
                {
                    if (PayPalPayment != null && PayPalPayment.PayPalInvoiceStatus == KNPIConstants.SENT)
                        yield return order;
                }                
            }         
            PXView.StartRow = 0;
            KNPIProcessOrders.Cache.IsDirty = false;      
        }
```

Can someone please help me out, as what I am doing wrong or what I am missing here.

Comment: How many pages of records on screen? Only one?

Comment: 1. Without Pagination getting 2 Pages of 33 records and with pagination implementation no records in the grid, for below condition.

if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.RE)
                {

                }

2. And for below condition Without Pagination getting 2 Pages of 35 records and with pagination implementation only 1 record displaying in the grid.

else if (filter.PayPalInvAction == KNPIConstants.CH)
{}